# Flutter Hero animation does not use theme colors?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

When creating a simple Hero animation with an icon in the appbar in a MaterialApp, the hero animation does not seem to use the theme color unless the color is explicitly specified in the icon itself.
Can someone explain why the color of the icon is changing during flight when the icon color is not explicitly set? Does the Hero not have access to the Theme data? Or does it use another color set?

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Hero(
          tag: "mytag",
          child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(
                Icons.menu,
                // uncomment below line and the flying icon is white as expected...
                // color: Theme.of(context).primaryIconTheme.color
              ),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(
                  PageRouteBuilder(
                    pageBuilder: 
                      (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => SecondPage()
                  )
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: <Widget> [
          Hero(
            tag: "mytag",
            child: Material(
              color: Colors.transparent,
                child: IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.menu,
                  // uncomment below line and the reverse flying icon is white as expected...
                  // color: Theme.of(context).primaryIconTheme.color
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).pop();
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ]
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because the flight animation of `Hero` is an `OverlayEntry` on `MaterialApp`. 
So while the widget used is the same (Icon), its location is not.

The thing is, in your case `IconTheme.of(context)` returns a different value based on that location:

- As a child of `AppBar`, `IconTheme` is overridden to handle `primaryColor` as background
- Everywhere else, it uses the default theme specified on `MaterialApp`.

So during the animation, the `IconTheme` used is a different one, leading to such issue.

---

A potential solution is to fix that value to make sure the `IconTheme` used is always the same:

```
AppBar(
  leading: Builder(
    builder: (context) {
      return Hero(
        child: IconTheme(
          data: Theme.of(context).primaryIconTheme,
          child: Icon(Icons.whatshot),
        ),
      );
    },
  ),
);
```

Comment: Ah, got it: So in the appbar `primaryIconTheme` is used, and during flight `iconTheme`, that is why the color is different. Thank you

Comment: When wrapping the button in a `Theme` widget, the icon is actually black all the way. Wrapping it in `IconTheme` with `data: Theme.of(context).primaryIconTheme` does do the trick. I'll stick with that, for if I ever choose to change the size or opacity.